# Why is the value not returned from the function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in an angular service:

```
factory.getList = function(){
      $http.get('/getClasses')
                    .success(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);

                        return(response);
                    })
                    .error(function() {
                        console.log('error in getList');
                    });
            };
```

When I run this I can see the response in the console, but in a controller I have:

```
$scope.classesList = Svc.getList();
```

and this classesList is always undefined. Why?

Comment: Your function ends before the data has returned. You need to read up on asynchronous calls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a asynchronous callback function, you need to do something as

first pass callb function to service

```
factory.getList = function(callb){
      $http.get('/getClasses')
                    .success(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);

                        callb(response);
                    })
                    .error(function() {
                        console.log('error in getList');
                    });
            };
```

then call it like this in controller

```
 Svc.getList(function(data){
 $scope.classesList=data;
 });
```